# How to balance load on multiple ubuntu servers?

Tags: networking, server, configuration

I want to create 2 servers(ubuntu) and a control node. I also want to deploy a website on 2 servers. Whenever any user tries to access the site request must be forwarded to the control node and according to the load on 2 servers(cpu usage, memory, no of users) request to be redirected.
Can you please guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for basically is something *like* haproxy. Except haproxy won't balance based on CPU usage or memory. It would be "limited" to the volume of connections to a given backend.

If you can make it work without CPU/mem-based checks, here's what you're looking for:

```
backend worker_backend
    balance     roundrobin
    option      httplog
    option      forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    default-server  inter 10s fall 2 rise 3
    option httpchk GET /ping HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ myservice.com
    server      back1 10.255.255.253:443 check weight 1 maxconn 4096 cookie check ssl verify none
    server      back2 10.255.255.254:443 check weight 1 maxconn 4096 cookie check ssl verify none

frontend worker
    bind        10.255.253.204:80
    redirect        scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
    bind        10.255.253.204:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/server.pem
    default_backend worker_backend
```